# Affine transform of multivariate gaussian

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, spectral-theory

If $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ are iid $N(0,1)$ or in other words $\mathbf{X}=(X_1, \ldots, X_n)$ is distributed $N(\mathbf{0}, \mathbf{I})$, then $A\mathbf{X}+\mu$ is distributed $N(\mu, AA^t)$. Showing that the covariance matrix becomes $AA^t$ is a mathematically well known result.

But I am having trouble seeing intuitively why the rigorous mathematics should end up with the result $AA^t$. For example consider the related example of $X=(X_1,X_2)$ distributed $N(0,C)$ where

$$C = \begin{pmatrix} \sigma_1^2 & 0 \\ 0 & \sigma_2^2 \end{pmatrix}$$ and $\sigma_1^2=1,\sigma_2^2=2$.

And consider the matrix

$$A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$ and the random vector $AX$. The random vector $X$ has density that looks like the left image (horribly drawn and not to scale). Since the effect of $AX$ should look something like the right image and since $A$ acts differently on the two axis why should resulting covariance matrix look like $ACA^t$.

The covariance matrix has the decomposition $C=UDU^t$ how can one see that the new covariance matrix $ACA^t=AUDU^tA^t$ has the intuitively expected orthogonal basis in its spectral decomposition?

[image]

Comment: I believe the way the "rigorous math" derives the covariance matrix $ACA^t$ is enough for my intuition. (Could the problem be the definition of the covariance matrix?)

Comment: Try Cross Validate. There might be someone who can answer you. Good luck ;)

Answer (score 1):

For help with the 'rigorous mathematics', there is a proof of the affine property [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/605816/proof-of-the-affine-property-of-normal-distribution-for-a-landscape-matrix).

Just substitute your $0$ for $\mu_x$, $I$ for $\Sigma_x$ and $\mu$ for $b$ and you should get the same result :)

For your 2nd question about the intuition for the spectral decomposition, we begin by observing that $C = UDU^T$, and that $U$ provides an orthogonal basis for the 'axes' of variation. In your example, the decomposition of $C$ would be $ICI$, where the axes are orthogonal to each other.

With $ACA^T$, we can rewrite it as $AUDU^{T}A^{T} = (AU)D(AU)^T$, where $AU$ is the new basis for the 'axes' of variation. You may think of it ($A$) intuitively, as a linear transformation of the basis $U$. Relating back to your example, the transformed basis for the axes of variation would be $AI = A = \left[
  \begin{array}{ c c }
     1 & 1 \\
     0 & 1
  \end{array} \right]$
Hope this helps!