# $X$ normally distributed in $\mathbb R^n$ iff components $x_i$ normally distributed?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory

We've had the normal distribution today in class and I was thinking about the following:

Let $X$ be normally distributed, $X\sim N(a,\Sigma)$ with a symmetric positive definite matrix $\Sigma$ and $b\in \mathbb R^n$. Can you follow that all components $x_i$ are normally distributed? If so how can you show it?

Conversly, if all components are normally distributed, can you follow $X$ is normally distributed?

I think that the second question is wrong and the first correct but I'm having troubles verfing it.

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are correct.

In regards to your first point, notice that affine transformations of jointly normally distributed random variables are again normally distributed. This has been discussed previously, e.g. [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/605816/proof-of-the-affine-property-of-normal-distribution-for-a-landscape-matrix). In your particular case, your affine transformation would just be the projection to the $i-th$ coordinate.

To your second point, let $X_1 \sim N(0,1)$ and set $X_1 = X_2$. Then it is easy to see that the covariance matrix $\Sigma$ of $X_1, X_2$ is not regular, hence not positive definite.

For another, more interesting example, see this [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normally_distributed_and_uncorrelated_does_not_imply_independent), which has some examples of normally distributed random variables, which are uncorrelated, but not independent. Now, assume these random variables were also jointly normally distributed, then they would be independent (because they are uncorrelated). Hence they are not jointly normally distributed.

Comment: If X1 is normal and X2=X1 then (X1,X2) is normal. Having a positive covariance matrix is not a prerequisite to be normal.

Comment: Ah, fair enough, thank you @Did! In some of my undergraduate courses it was actually defined based on a positive definite covariance matrix, so that e.g. the affine transformation property required a full rank linear operator to a space of lower (or the same) dimension. But I suppose this was just the case, because it enabled the definition of normal distributions in terms of pdfs, thus simplifying things.