# Proving linear transformation of gaussian using generalized inverse.

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, probability-theory, normal-distribution

I was trying see if there was a way to prove the property of linear transformations of gaussian distributions without using the characteristic function.

I came across the answer at the bottom:

[Proof of the affine property of normal distribution for a landscape matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/605816/proof-of-the-affine-property-of-normal-distribution-for-a-landscape-matrix)

Where the writer references the generalized inverse. This appears to work except I get stuck at the final covariance matrix formula as I don't see an obvious way to collapse the generalized inverse into the covariance matrix. Using the pseudo-inverse it comes down to showing that:

$$ ((A^TA)^{-1}A^T)^T \Sigma^{-1} ((A^TA)^{-1}A^T) = (A \Sigma A^T)^{-1} $$

I suspect this can be done but I'm not sure how.

Comment: Thinking about this more it's actually immediate I think because from the perspective of computing vector values (A^TA)^(-1)A^T)^(-1) = A hmm

Comment: I'd strongly advise against using a downvoted answer as a reference. For non-singular $\mathbf{A}$, the approach makes sense as for a given $\mathbf{y}$, there is only one unique $\mathbf{x}$. For non-singular matrix, when you use generalized inverse, you only calculate the probability of one possible $\mathbf{x}$ out of infinitely many possible $\mathbf{x}$